# Not able to boot system after installing MX Linux

Tags: multi-boot, lenovo-laptop, pxe

I'm unable to boot the system after installing MX Linux..

- I'm trying to dual boot MX Linux and Windows 10. After installing MX Linux, I'm getting a black screen with this error at boot time. I tried changing the boot order from the BIOS and updating grub by installation media, but without success.
- Laptop config: 4GB, 500GB, Intel Pentium B960, Lenovo G580 laptop with BIOS boot and MBR partition system

```
Intel UNDI. PXE-2.0 (build 083)
Copyright (C) 1997-2008  Intel Corporation

For Atheros PCIE Ethernet Controller v2.1.

Pair No. 0000 CDT status=0200
Pair No. 0001 CDT status=0201
CDT detect return 0000

Check cable connection!
PXE-MOF: Exiting Intel PXE ROM.
```

Comment: What you wrote as comments should be in the question itself. Please [edit] accordingly and also add hardware specifications as there are several generations with the same model name.

Comment: When you installed MX, what options did you pick?  PXE is associated with booting from a network, which is why it's complaining about a missing Ethernet cable.

Comment: @fixer1234 could you please elaborate about options?

Comment: With a Pentium B960 the system is UEFI, not BIOS. Why did you installed in Legacy mode? Was Windows installed in Legacy as well? WHY? Really, if you purposefully installed Windows in Legacy that's insane. However, if Windows was preinstalled then it's UEFI (as it should be). Installing the second OS in a different mode would explain a lot of what's going on. The options asked above are the BOOT options.

Comment: GabrielaGarcia beat me to it. I'm not familiar with MX's options. Some distros let you explicitly pick a network boot (which may have led to selecting it unintentionally). But the system may fall back to this mode in the absence of a usable boot specification. The G580 is a pretty old computer, or at least has been around for awhile. Did you upgrade an older version of Windows to Win 10? Does the laptop have UEFI, which you set to legacy mode, or BIOS? If every OS isn't installed consistent with the laptop configuration, it will cause boot problems, and may be why you're seeing this.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia as you've seen in my question, I'm having BIOS mode with MBR partition style and in order to run OS in UEFI, we must use GPT partition style. Therefore, I'd to install MX Linux in legacy mode. I know G580 is pretty old to handle all this, but I've been using with other OSes in dual boot and it's been working fine for me.

Comment: Though, I've solved it! Windows 10 startup repair removed specified ethernet cable error and then gave me "grub rescue" shell at startup. Used supergrubdisk to boot into linux and updated grub and booooom! it worked!!! Thanks both of you for your time.

Comment: @fixer1234 The same marque (model) has been reused for several generations. Certainly all the models with i3/i7 and also the one OP has (I think) are UEFI. So, even if old... 1. Not that old really and 2. All OSes should be installed in UEFI. The OP solved the issue temporarily, for this laptop. I bet they will make the same exact mistake in the next one.

Comment: @ArjunMota, kudos for solving this.  Consider posting an answer describing your solution.  That will be helpful to others with a similar problem.  Then 2 days after you posted the question, you can accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark that will appear next to it.  That will indicate that the problem has been solved.